# Needed to change slug to access page

Tags: url-rewriting, slug, template-hierarchy

I've created a page, with the slug "news". Something happened because now I can't access /news .. I needed to change the slug to "news_", or something, to access that page. 
I checked the database to see if some ghost data stood there, but i've found nothing. 
I've tried to update the permalinks but it didn't resolve this issue.
Deleting and creating again the Page don't work either..

What might be causing this error? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more what happens? You say you can't access the page, but if you visit `/news/` what do you get? Do you have any post types or taxonomies called `news`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have deleted completely all previous pages with the slug 'news' ?

When you click on Trash,  the page/post is only placed into the Trash folder, not deleted. You must then empty the trash folder to completely delete the page.

If the old page remains in the trash folder and you generate a new page using the identical slug WordPress will automatically change the slug to something like /news-2/  so that it can differentiate the two pages you have generated.

That is probably why you were able to access the new page using /news_/  It was a different slug from the original.